# Find the code in microsoft project

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have a form in Microsoft project 2007 that is pinned into the ribbon. When I want to use it in Microsoft project 2010 the form is not showing and is not pinned, so the same project I have saved and can open in 2007 and see the pinned form is not shown when I open it on a another computer with 2010 version.

I went to the organizer to see if I can find it, but I didnt find it. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file in MS Project and press Alt + F11 to open the VBA editor.  You should see the Project Explorer on the left hand side.

Expand forms.
Double-click one of the forms. 
Select the visual form.
Press F5.

Also, search your VBA code (forms and modules) for the word Private. Change Private to Public so they appear in the organizer modules.